# MongoDB pull based on partial array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I can do a `$pull` for a simple document:

```
> db.users.find();
{ "_id" : 4, "sessions" : [ { "sid" : "foo1" }, { "sid" : "bar" } ] }

> db.users.update({}, {"$pull": {sessions: {"sid" : "bar"}}});
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

But if I have more information on the session:

```
> db.users.insert({_id:5, sessions: [ { sid: "foo"}, {sid:"bar", ssid:"test"}]});
> db.users.find();
{ "_id" : 4, "sessions" : [ { "sid" : "foo1" } ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "sessions" : [ { "sid" : "foo" }, { "sid" : "bar", "ssid" : "test" } ] }

> db.users.update({}, {"$pull": {sessions: {"sid" : "bar"}}});
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

then the `$pull` fails.

Comment: Umm. Your query matches both documents and you forgot the "multi" param. The update would work as expected if it matched the right document, or affected both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$pull` is correct, but you need to add the `multi: true` option for the `update` to apply to both docs:

```js
db.users.update({}, {"$pull": {sessions: {"sid" : "bar"}}}, {multi: true});
```